# XCode v12.4 refuses to open

Tags: xcode

I am new to Mac.

I installed XCode v12.4, on my Mac Mini with Mac OS 10.15.7. I also Installed the Command line tools for XCode v12.4

When I type `open /Applications/Xcode.app` I dont get any output and the XCode Icon starts bouncing in the taskbar. But it stops bouncing but keeps a small white circle underneth the icon.

When I rightclick the Xcode icon in the taskbar and select `show all windows` then it says `No Available Windows`

When looking at my Activity Monitor, `Xcode` shows up and a few seconds later `com.apple.dt.Xcode.DeveloperSystemPolicyService`

Answer (score 1):

This means XCode is already open, you will see the menu bar at the top change.

To see a Window, click on Xcode in the taskbar, and click on Window => Welcome to Xcode at the top of your screen